# Convert json data with arrays into CSV

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to understand best practices for parsing and creating a CSV file from a set of json, which could change for each API call. This has to do with Facebook adset data.

Here is an example of output data:

```
{
                "lifetime_imps": 0,
                "optimization_goal": "REACH",
                "optimization_sub_event": "NONE",
                "pacing_type": [
                    "standard"
                ],
                "promoted_object": {
                    "application_id": "123456789",
                    "custom_event_type": "PURCHASE",
                    "object_store_url": "https://itunes.apple.com/app/god"
                },
                "recurring_budget_semantics": true,
                "review_feedback": "[]",
                "custom_audiences": [
                {
                    "id": "123455678919",
                    "name": "GODS_COUNTRY_REALLY_GOOD_SONG"
                }
            ]
}
```

**Concerns:**
When we parse this structure, it's possible that for example the pacing_type array could have more than 1 element. Or even the custom_audiences, has a number of objects that may change depending on the product.

The goal is to parse this structure and create a CSV file, which can be used downstream in an analytics based or reporting software.

Possible method - Collect all elements of the JSON structure that are fixed and for each element that contains a value of array, create a new row for each element in the array ?

Comment: Can you show what you expect the CSV to look like? Have you seen the Pandas normalize JSON output?

Comment: Also, are you expecting the same number of columns if there are multiple array items vs without?

Comment: CSV is not a good format for representing nested data, especially when the nested data varies in unpredictable ways.

Comment: @martineau what do you recommend?

Comment: Well. (obviously) JSON supports it, as well as YAML and XML. If you really prefer CSV, perhaps creating multiple "linked" files from the single source would be feasible. One way to do the linking could done by putting filenames of the nested data in the main or "root" CSV file.

Comment: @martineau I thought about that too, basically a database, but in csv format

Comment: CSV format is relatively easy to read and write, which would make "extending" it somehow to support nesting feasible to implement yourself — however doing so would make it non-conformant to the standard and likely not able to be read or written using Python's `csv` module in the standard library (as well as many other third-party) modules.

Answer (score 1):

Find the longest most nested to-be-a-row element and use that number of cells to pad all the shorter ones to:

```
1,short,,,,,
2,longest,a,b,c,d,e
3,short,q,x,z,,
```